# по пути /sitemap.xml выдаёт ошибку ругаясь на файл ../image.php

Tags: php, sitemap, opencart3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по пути /sitemap.xml выдаёт ошибку ругаясь на файл ../image.php и на его методы, может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной ошибкой ?

скриншот кода, функции resize
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Верия php на сервере соответствует требованиям движка?

Comment: Что делает файл sitemap.xml? И есть ли вызовы image.php до момента перехода на sitemap.xml?

Comment: Верия php на сервере соответствует

Comment: Если происходит такая ошибка, я думаю что всё таки есть вызовы, сайтмапа генерится с помощью модуля google_sitemap, просто делается редирект на sitemap.xml.

Comment: @МэлБроневик, как так что версия php отсутсвует? Добавьте код с image.php файла вопрос с 70 по 90 линию. И скажите какая версия php установлена.

Comment: @Mully не "отсутствует" а "соответствует" =) это ответ на первый комментарий. Скрин сейчас будет.

Comment: @Mully PHP Version 7.0.32-0

Comment: Что так же на 50 строчке image.php?

Answer (score 0):

У вас параметр `$this->image` является типом `boolean`. Скорее всего потому что вы его где-то не переопределили. Также может быть потому вы на 73 строчке создаете изображение `$this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $heigth)` и отправляете в `$width` и `$height` значения равные 0, что приводит к тому что метод вам не возвращает `resource`, а возвращает `boolean` => а дальше у вас уже весь код крашится, и кидает warning'и что у вас `$this->image` это `boolean`, а ожидается тип `resource`.

Comment: мне просто кажется что дело не в коде. На другом сайте, на базе которого был сделан этот, работает всё. Нужно конечно глянуть на него, возможно там что-то правилось таки

Comment: В выведенных ошибках все написано, именно то что вы передаете не тот тип. Нужно копать в сторону `$this->image` и выяснять почему ей присваивается значение `true` или `false`.